# How to auto-select a selectOneRadio on the basis of selection of another selectOneRadio in primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, selectoneradio

I have two `SelectOneRadio` menus in an `xhtml` form.

How can I automatically select a  `radiobutton`, in the second menu, on the basis of the selection of a `radiobutton` in the first menu?

Comment: You can use `p:ajax` on first component, in the listener set value of the second one and update both ones. Also post your code attempt if you expect someone to help and have a look here on how to ask questions: [mcve].

Comment: Update your code also, what did u try?